# How to open a webpage in html without clicking a link/button

Tags: javascript, html

Before I start I would like to say that I am completely new to HTML and have limited programming experience however **I am doing a school project** and need to understand how to do this. I have looked everywhere but couldn't seem to find any answers so I came here.

I need to know how to get a html script to open a new webpage without external inputs (such as pressing a link). Below are a few of the simple things I have tried to do to open google using html.

Comment: "Below are a few of the simple things" Where?

Comment: If your script simply changes the window.location to a new pages address, it'll be called with no input. Be warned, the next step is what gets LOTS of people in trouble -- opening new windows and setting their locations without user input. That's a popup, most  browsers block them. Don't do it.

Comment: you will need to use javascript for this

Comment: but when do you want to open the web page. on which event occurrence?

Answer (score -1):

This can very easily be done with:

```
window.location.href = "[URL_HERE]";
```

No click event is required, just run the line of code when you want to change the URL.